# how to use sed replace string pattern with backslash

Tags: linux, replace, sed, backslash

I want to do replace for the following patterns (the foregoing rule has higher priority)

```
\right)   -> remain unchanged
\right )  -> remain unchanged
\right]   -> remain unchanged
\right ]  -> remain unchanged
\right}   -> remain unchanged
\right }  -> remain unchanged
\ri)      -> \right)
\ri       -> \rightarrow
\right    -> \rightarrow
```

In other words, if there is any parentheses bracket or brace, I want to have \right, if anything else, it should be replaced by \rightarrow. In short, I was trying transform a lot of shorthanded google doc equations with into proper LaTeX format. What I came up with was the following

```
sed -i 's/\\ri\([^g]\)/\\right\1/g' $tempfile1  #first step substitution
sed -i 's/\\right\([^])}>|a]\)/\\rightarrow\1/g' $tempfile1 
sed -i 's/\\right \([^])}>|a]\)/\\rightarrow \1/g' $tempfile1
```

It works ok except it does not change \right\ into \rightarrow\ as expected. My test input tempfile1 is the following

```
\ri\right\right \right)\right]\right }\right )\ri \right ]\righta \al \\
```

It goes into

```
\rightarrow\right\rightarrow \right)\right]\right }\right )\rightarrow \right ]\rightarrow \alpha \\
```

Noting that the \right\ part was not done correctly. Then I added the following line, thinking that it will explicit pick up what was left, however, it does not work as expected and now I am really confused...

```
sed -i 's/\\right\\/\\rightarrow\\/g' $tempfile1 #why this does not work
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Surely you could combine your 3 scripts into one using `sed -i -e '...pattern1...' -e '...pattern2...' -e '...pattern3...' ...`.  For kilobyte-size files, three passes probably don't matter much, but for multi-megabyte files and bigger, one pass vs three can make a big difference.

Comment: I see, thx. The typical file size for me is less than 50K (normal LaTeX documents), but I have 30+ pattern (eg. \al\beta\del\b\i\sig) to replace and the number increases in time. (Thanks google doc for its Equation Editor and the recent "improvements" they made)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble occurs when the expression:

```
sed -i 's/\\right\([^])}>|a]\)/\\rightarrow\1/g'
```

is applied to:

```
\right\right\
```

The first match reads `\right\` and replaces it with `\rightarrow\`; the problem occurs when the scan resumes, it starts at the `r` of the second `right`, not with the backslash (that was part of the previous match).

The simple trick is to repeat the command...

```
sed -i -e 's/\\right\([^])}>|a]\)/\\rightarrow\1/g' \
       -e 's/\\right\([^])}>|a]\)/\\rightarrow\1/g'
```

The rescan deals with the second `\right\` sequence by starting *ab initio* again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, now I think I understand better. In my real problem, I actually have more than 30+ patterns, so I shall just simply repeat the whole script again.

Comment: That may work well enough.  Alternatively, you could use Perl or Python instead of `sed` and use trailing context in the patterns so that the second backslash in `\right\` is not part of the first match and the repeat continues where you want it to.

Comment: I have to study those things, I know that sed is not good at manipulating multi-line document, therefore I cannot properly treat them, for example, once spot a \\ (double backslach) I need to add a \n (endline) and an additional & at the beginning of the next line if they are not there already. (\alpha\\\beta goes to \alpha\n&\beta) This is for proper alignment of equations array. I know perl should easily handle this, but it seems to much for sed.

Comment: I'd say `sed` handles multi-line documents (files) fine; it doesn't handle multi-line patterns anywhere near as easily.  I'm not clear that you have to worry about multi-line patterns in your work, though.  You might need to consider whether your code handles `\ri` at the end of a line, for example.  I've not reviewed your patterns for that.